# Embed Background Audio in Android >= 2.3 Browser

Tags: android, html, audio, mobile, mpeg

This question has been asked before, but all of the threads I have found have been regarding Android 2.2 and earlier.

I am working on a mobile site that needs to embed a live mpeg-type stream. I would prefer that the stream continue playing even after the browser is closed.

If you navigate your Android phone to [Grooveshark's Experimental Mobile Site](http://html5.grooveshark.com/), you can see that it is definitely possible to do this, provided your OS is greater than 2.2. Any idea how they were able to do this?

Comment: when you say "close" the browser, do you mean switch to a different app or the home screen?

Comment: Either one. I want to be able to play background audio when you are either on the home screen or in another app that isn't playing audio itself. As I said, Grooveshark can do it, so there must be some way.

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me on my Android phone

```
<audio id="audio1" controls="controls" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" >
   <source src="scene1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="scene1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

I put the .mp3 line above the .ogg (before it was not working with .ogg above .mp3)

Comment: Which Android version are you using?