# Playing audio with HTML5 in Android browser

Tags: android, html, audio, browser, mp3

I want to play audio in the **Android** browser, using the **html5** `<audio>` tag. It works fine in the iPhone browser, but not in Android. I'm using **Android Virtual Device 4.0.3**.

Does anyone know why?

The Android source:

> `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.html");`

The HTML file:

```
<audio controls="controls" format="mp3">
    <source src="achievement.mp3" /> 
</audio>
```

(i couldn't hear the audio with `<embed>` and `<object>` tags either)

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here 
[Embed Background Audio in Android >= 2.3 Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505228/embed-background-audio-in-android-2-3-browser)

```
<audio id="audio1" controls="controls" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" >
   <source src="scene1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="scene1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

it's work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search and found [this issue report on google code.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10546)  It seems the  tag is unsupported.  However, the  tag is and can play mp3 files.  The down side is (if I read it correctly) that the controls are not available.  Give it a read and let us know how you make out.

I found another question that has lots of different possible solutions: [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069124/playing-html5-audio-in-android-browser)

Comment: I think the problem is only for Android 2.x. It should work for Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: I found lots of different issues with several versions of android.  The general concencus was that it was supposed to be fixed but is still broken.  You may be right though I haven't had the time to try it out.

Comment: Actually, I didn't try myself, I am just relying on this: http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android40/ios50.html