# What type of audio file to use for UI sounds in a web app?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I couldn't find an answer on StackOverflow that dealt with audio formats. I've come across some methods on how to implement sounds in UI (like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42755) one), but what type of audio file type should I be using that will work across all devices including PCs, tablets, and phones for an HTML/CSS/JS based web app? Right now, my sounds only work on a PC and not on mobile when a certain button is clicked. I am using .ogg as my audio file.

```
// Source: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21604/playing-sound-on-a-button-click/42755#42755
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var obj = document.createElement("audio"); 
    obj.setAttribute("src", "link/to/audio/click.mp3"); 
    $.get(); 

    $(".playSound").click(function() { 
        obj.play(); 
    }); 
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: wav, mp3 and ogg is most useful extension.

Comment: @Reza-S4 When I use a .mp3 file using the code above, the sound still doesn't work in mobile.

Comment: are you test AAC format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Android has a chrome-based browser and webview by default, and iOS safari.

Windows phone has a IE browser.

Comment: Thank you. That's a really informational chart. But when I use a .mp3 file using the code above, the sound still doesn't work in mobile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900816/playing-audio-with-html5-in-android-browser